# Migrating users and IIS settings from a workgroup win2k3 machine to a new win2k8r2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, migration, user-accounts

I am retiring my old Windows Server 2003 Standard 32bit machine and migrating to a faster and more powerful new machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

The two sticking points are migrating user accounts (and there are a lot of them) and IIS settings/websites (again, there are a lot).

The new machine has not been provisioned yet. I'm at that point where I'm about install the OS on it.
The old machine is configured with a mirrored set for its OS and data partitions. I have broken the mirror set, replicated all of the data to an external drive, and then rebuilt the mirror set. In short, I have an image of the old machine to play with while safely leaving it up and running.

Thanks!